# Airflow Dag failure callback being called multiple times

Tags: python, airflow

I have a problem with `on_failure_callback` feature being called multiple times.

Currently, my main **Dag** is split into 1 **PythonOperator** and 4 **SubDag**, each **SubDag** consists in multiple **PythonOperator**.

```
t_python_1 >> t_subdag_2 >> t_subdag_3 >> t_subdag_4 >> t_subdag_5

__t_subdag_2__:
t_sub2_python_1 >> t_sub2_python_2 t_sub2_python_3

...
```

During setup, in **default_args** of main **Dag**, I add a `on_failure_callback` option. And for each **SubDag**, I set it to `None`.

Args main `Dag`:

```
DEFAULT_ARGS_MAINDAG = {
    "owner"               : "airflow",
    "depends_on_past"     : False,
    "start_date"          : days_ago(2),
    "retries"             : 2,
    "retry_delay"         : timedelta(seconds=30),
    "on_failure_callback" : custom_failure_handle,
}
```

Args `SubDag`:

```
DEFAULT_ARGS_SUBDAG = {
    "owner"               : "airflow",
    "depends_on_past"     : False,
    "start_date"          : days_ago(2),
    "retries"             : 2,
    "retry_delay"         : timedelta(seconds=30),
    "on_failure_callback" : None,
}
```

But when I run the **Dag** and inspect tasks, it seems that every subdag's tasks have `on_failure_callback` set to **custom_failure_handle** instead of being `None`.
So during execution, if a **SubDag** task fails, `on_failure_callback` is called twice : in the main **Dag** and in the **SubDag**.

Is this possible to have a separate configuration for parent **Dag** and **SubDag** to be sure that the failure callback is not being called twice?

Comment: it could be because you have `"retries": 2` configured; so the `on_failure_callback` is invoked upon every failed attempt (although technically then it should be called thrice: original run failure + 2 retry attempt failures)

Comment: @y2k-shubham isn't it supposed to be called only after all retries failed?

Comment: ok my bad; i mixed it up with `on_retry_callback`. **Zat42** yes indeed `on_failure_callback` is [supposed to be invoked](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#:~:text=on_failure_callback%20(callable)%20%E2%80%93%20a%20function,single%20parameter%20to%20this%20function.&text=on_retry_callback%20(callable)%20%E2%80%93%20much%20like,is%20executed%20when%20retries%20occur.) only when task is finally marked `FAILED` (not on intermittent failures since at that time the status of task is `UP_FOR_RETRY`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not on `Airflow` side but in the way I implemented a service that create **default_args** for my `SubDag`. Basically `SubDag` **default_args** were always override by main `Dag` parameters.

You can of course pass a different configuration for each `SubDag` by the same way you do for a regular `Dag`.